# How can I cache a local copy of Google's Maven Repo?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I'm trying to download a stable version of Google's Maven Repo (https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#) on my local machine.  This is part of a larger effort for offline Android Development.  The goal is to cache the repo's vast amount of dependencies (to include legacy versions for compatibility issues) so I can use Gradle build-scripts and use the required dependencies locally rather than having to rely on an active internet connection and need to reach remote repositories.

Without adding each individual dependency to my build.gradle(app) file, is there a way I can download the entire repo and have my build.gradle use it?

I've added common dependencies to my build.gradle(app) but still want to have the flexibility of adding more functionality later on (again, without internet access).

Comment: `clone maven repo` turns up lots of information in a major search engine, including https://stackoverflow.com/q/12127441/115145 and https://github.com/netmikey/mvncloner.

Comment: I strongy recommend to install a repository manager  afterwards build your projects ones and you have everything in the repository manager ... after that you can turn off the internet connection...