# Override sbt default resolvers with authenticated repo?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a maven repository with authentication, and I want sbt to use only the maven repository

My build.sbt:

```
resolvers += "My Repo" at "https://my.repository.addresss/repo/"

externalResolvers <<= resolvers map { rs =>
    Resolver.withDefaultResolvers(rs, mavenCentral = false)
}
```

But when I type `sbt clean compile`, it is still download from repo1.maven.org, I can not override it!

As my maven repo has to authenticate, so it always fails when I put default repo config in ~/.sbt/repositories

Is there any way that I can use my repo only, and authenticate successful?

Comment: I tested your config with `inspect resolvers` and `show external-resolvers`. It show me absolutely proper values without mavenCentral. IMHO you may open bug ticket in your case at https://github.com/sbt/sbt-git.

Comment: https://github.com/sbt/sbt of course

Comment: @Ezhik although it does show the proper values, but still download from repo1.maven.org when `sbt compile`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770125/how-do-i-get-sbt-to-use-a-local-maven-proxy-repository-nexus - I think this is an answer for your question. But if you post a bug report it would be right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a secured Nexus with sbt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348805/how-to-access-a-secured-nexus-with-sbt)

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, I can only help you with one part of your question.

If you only want to use your maven repo, have a look at the sbt documentation, chapter [proxy repositories](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Proxy-Repositories.html#sbt-configuration). There the file ~/.sbt/repositories is used. Alternatively, you can also use sbt.boot.properties (see [Launcher configuration](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Launcher.html#configuration)).

Don't forget to override the build repos from the build scripts as documented [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Proxy-Repositories.html#launcher-script). If
you don't do that, sbt still tries to connect to repo1.maven.org.

I did the same thing today (using sbt 0.12.3), and it works!

Answer (score 1):

### Try this:

```
lazy val yourRepo = "yourRepo" at "https://yourRepo.com/nexus/content/groups/public"

fullResolvers := {
    val oldResolvers = fullResolvers.value
    val idx = oldResolvers.map(_.isInstanceOf[DefaultMavenRepository$]).indexOf(true)
    oldResolvers.take(idx) ++ Seq(yourRepo) ++ oldResolvers.drop(idx)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've met similar situation of yours. The solution is

1. create `~/.ivy2/.credentials` with

   ```
   realm=Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager
   host=yourRepo.com
   user=yourUser
   password=yourpassword
   ```
2. add this line to `build.sbt`

   ```
   credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".ivy2" / ".credentials")
   ```
3. create `~/.sbt/repositories` according to http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html