# Make sbt completely forget repo.scala-sbt.org and repo.typesafe.com

Tags: sbt, artifactory, resolver

I'm working on some sbt 0.13.5 projects which pulls over 100 dependencies to compile. It takes ~1s to reach servers like `typesafe.com`/`scala-sbt.org`/`maven.org` from here in Korea, which makes the dependency resolution take hours to finish. So I've managed to set up sbt to use an [artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) mirror installed on the local network, by:

● Save `~/.sbt/repositories` as follows,

```
[repositories]
  local
  ivy-proxy-releases: http://artifactory.local:8088/artifactory/ivy-release, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  maven-proxy-releases: http://artifactory.local:8088/artifactory/libs-release
  maven-proxy-shapshots: http://artifactory.local:8088/artifactory/libs-snapshot
```

● Add the following line at the top of `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/build.sbt`

```
sbtResolver := Resolver.url("ivy proxy repo", url("http://artifactory.local:8088/artifactory/ivy-release"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

● Add the same line to the local project directory's `./project/plugins.sbt`

By doing these I could drastically reduce the time took to pull dependency jars, but sbt was still accessing `repo.scala-sbt.org` and `repo.typesafe.com` just to get some 404 (with a big latency).

So only after I did `/etc/hosts` trick to point those domains to a dummy web server I could achieve the shortest build time. (~2 minutes to pull all dependencies and compile the `play-scala` example)

Is there a setting that can make sbt to completely forget the `scala-sbt` and `typesafe` repos and only work with the configured local proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the build repos with the setting sbt.override.build.repos, like shown here: [sbt doc](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html#Launcher+Script).
There is also an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939280/is-there-any-way-to-completely-override-sbt-default-resolvers) to a similar question.