# How to only use private Maven repository for SBT?

Tags: sbt

We have a company Nexus, and our company is behind a restrictive proxy. How do I tell SBT to only use this Nexus server?

When I create an SBT project in IDEA, I get "error while importing sbt project". I the tried to add this line to my `build.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "Company NEXUS" at "http://our.nexus.com/content/groups/public/"
```

But IDEA tells me it cannot resolve symbol `+=` and when I try `sbt compile` on the console I get tons of "connection refused" because it tries to connect to repo1.maven.org and oss.sonatype.org.

So, how do I configure this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [how do I get sbt to use a local maven proxy repository (Nexus)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770125/how-do-i-get-sbt-to-use-a-local-maven-proxy-repository-nexus)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15842275/463761), which references the documentation on [Proxy Repositories](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html).

Comment: I tried this, but I cannot get it to work. I have another problem I ask in another question.