# How do I get sbt behind a corporate firewall?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to run SBT behind a corporate firewall. Another colleague has kindly set up a Nexus-based proxy.

I've set up my ~/.sbt/repositories file as follows:

```
[repositories]
local
central: http://dev.reallysecurecompany.com:8000/nexus/content/repositories/central/
```

But when I try to run SBT it crashes almost imediatly with the error message: UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES. org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.12: not found

I can see from the error that it tried to fetch down:
    http://dev.reallysecurecompany:8000/nexus/content/repositories/central/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.12/sbt-0.13.12.pom

The odd thing is that sbt-0.13.12 dosen't seem like a legit version.  I did a nexus search for sbt, and it did find the following, but that's sbt-interface and not sbt:

http://dev.reallysecurecompany.com:8000/nexus/service/local/repositories/central/content/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-interface/0.13.12/sbt-interface-0.13.12.jar

It looks like sbt 0.13.12 is not a real thing, at least not on Maven Central:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22sbt%22%20AND%20v%3A%220.13.11%22

So what's my solution? Is there a way I can get the right thing? What can I give it to make it happy?

Comment: sbt 0.13.12 is real: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sbt-dev/fBzSAyVL4DQ

Comment: Download it somewhere else outside the firewall. Move the jars to local ivy directory.

Comment: make sure that your Nexus is mirroring Typesafe Repo as well: https://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/0.13.12/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I get sbt to use a local maven proxy repository (Nexus)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770125/how-do-i-get-sbt-to-use-a-local-maven-proxy-repository-nexus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sbt 0.13.12 is real:

http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sbt-dev/fBzSAyVL4DQ

https://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/0.13.12/

Sbt doesn't release to Central Repo (Maven) much, so your Nexus should mirror Typesafe Repo (Bintray) as well:

https://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/maven-releases/