# SBT - invalid system property 'sbt.repository.config'

Tags: scala, build, sbt, nexus

I am trying to build SBT project where I am pulling dependencies from internal repository. I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770125/how-do-i-get-sbt-to-use-a-local-maven-proxy-repository-nexus) to set repo.properties & stbconfig.txt. Here is the content of these files- 
**stbconfix.txt -**
[image]

**repo.properties-**

[image]

After all above steps, SBT should have automatically pulled dependencies from internal repository but it isn't. 
After that, I am trying to pass repo.properties path in command line but it is throwing error too-
[image]

No idea why it is complaining with invalid system property for 'sbt.repository.config'. Any help is very much appreciated.

Note- I tried upgrading SBT and installed it 2-3 times. I am currently on SBT 0.13.13.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the required property to SBT_OPTS environment variable before running sbt:

```
SET SBT_OPTS=-Dsbt.repository.config="your repo.properties path here"
sbt
```